# How to create database table without using migration Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, web, laravel-4

Now I am developing an application for Office attendance marking in Laravel. There are different divisions in office. Each divisions are created by Admin. If admin creates new division, table to enter attendance should be created. This should be created automatically with division creation.

How will I create table without using Migration in Laravel?

Each attendance table should be created with a name `"division_name_attendance"`. It should contain following fields.

```
Id (primary key)
user_id (varchar)
date (date)
timestamp
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You could do this, but it is not the best solution. The best solution is to create a table `divisions` and use a column `division_id` in this table. When you deploy an application, your database structure should never change at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply use Schema Builder when creating a division: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema

In your controller (or route callback, or service method, no difference), use this code:

```
Schema::create('division_name_attendance', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->date('date');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Of course in this case division name should be dynamic, I'm not sure how do you get this variable. It may be POST or GET variable, etc. Let me know if you need help on this.